# No units in OnSemi datasheet for capacitor, what is the default unit?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I can't figure out what the units are for the capacitors for [this voltage regulator.](https://at.rs-online.com/web/p/spannungsregler/7862426)

I can't find anything in the datasheet that gives me a hint.

[image: Voltage Regulator datasheet]

Comment: Welcome! Bad form on their part. Probably uF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old lazy way of specifying capacitor values:

- If all the digits are behind the decimal, it's in microfarads -- i.e., 0.0047 means \$0.0047 \mu \mathrm F\$ or \$4.7 \mathrm {nF}\$.
- If it's got digits in front of the decimal *and* it's marked as an electrolytic (i.e. there's a '+' sign someplace) then it's in microfarads -- which is the case here, where 2200 means \$2200 \mu \mathrm F\$.
- If it's got digits in front of the decimal and it's *not* marked as an electrolytic then it's in picofarads (or in *really* old books micro-micro-farads).  I.e., "330" means \$330 \mathrm{pF}\$.

It really all boils down to "you're just supposed to know".  As far as I'm concerned it's bad practice -- it's not like you have to spend $10 every time you write a \$\mu\$.  But it's good to be aware that it's out there.

Historical example showing a note:

[image: Schematic with units note]
Source: ARRL, *The Radio Amateur's Handbook*, 53rd ed. (1976), p.95

Curiously, this also contains a ".33µF", though ".1" and ".47" appear elsewhere in the book.  It might be used inconsistently, but at least it's being more specific.

Also noteworthy, they omitted the leading zero for decimals, which is probably more robust to printing/copying errors; including the leading zero might make "0.01" get misinterpreted as "[.]001".  Publishers / drafters had many minor variations in rules like these.  Or for a less minor variation, see [RKM code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKM_code), widely used in Europe.

Comment: Back in the day, this was common practice, *and noted as such on the schematic* -- in a corner somewhere perhaps, along with other notes in a block -- as you would in traditional mechanical drafting.  Also interesting that, despite "nano" being introduced a pretty long time ago, it wasn't adopted until relatively recently (say, 70s-90s? -- not sure on exact range, I'm not much of a service schematics aficionado).

Comment: I remember well the app who was building these data-sheets at the 52nd-street in Phoenix, he sure didn't want his colleagues to add units in any way. It was quite some time ago now...

Comment: I was going to refute you by looking in my old ARRL handbooks -- and there it was, a little section calling out the meaning of the decimals.  I still think including the units is better.

Comment: (note: micromicrofarads and picofarads are the same unit, just different names. Before SI prefixes were standardized, μμF was the usual way of writing what we would today call pF)

Comment: @TimWescott would you add a scan/reference to the ARRL info?  That's really helpful.

Comment: Does this mean that nF or mF are never used? Only μF and pF and you tell the difference by how large the numbers are?

Comment: Most schematics I've seen lately use \$\mathrm{\mu F}\$, \$\mathrm{n F}\$, and \$\mathrm{p F}\$.  American tradition tends to avoid the \$\mathrm{n F}\$ in favor of fractional \$\mathrm{\mu F}\$.  I _think_ that tradition is fading.  \$\mathrm{m F}\$ is rarely used, as far as I can tell, in favor of tens of thousands of \$\mathrm{\mu F}\$, or fractional Farads.

Comment: Oh yeah good idea, ARRL handbooks. Actually as long as I'm around, I've got a 1976 copy to hand, let me put that in real quick. Page 95 isn't the first schematic listing units, and there are also schematics (earlier and later) showing values but no units or notes. They were a bit inconsistent with the use of notes I think, but the units are always consistent with the above default, so the reader will eventually pick that up I think. (Interestingly, Fig 3-25 (p.78) specifies µF by default, but mixes no-units and "µF" units on the same schematic, how redundant! :) )

Comment: N.b.: There's a historically good reason not to use "mF": "mf" (lower case) used to be used for micro-Farads, because who knew how to write \$\mu\$?  This was back when they also used "mmf" instead of "pF", but I would not be surprised if there isn't some schematic in use _today_ that has "mf" in it, because the piece of equipment Just Won't Die.

Comment: Doesn't help that you still see capacitors to this day in "MF" or "MFD".  The datasheet might even be using SI units, but the part label alone might cause confusion, go figure :)

Comment: If you don't have a computer and the drawing doesn't fit in a typewriter, then all the lettering was done by hand. Ask yourself how many \$\mu F\$ would you hand letter before making a note that all capacitors without units would are in \$\mu F\$. There are many other standard drawing shortcuts that come from hand drawing and lettering.

Answer (score 13):

They are microfarads, with C<sub>in</sub> being 330 μF, C<sub>O</sub> will be the same units, 2200 μF.  The [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/d568/0900766b81574655.pdf) certainly should say, rather than let you guess.

You can tell because they are polarised on the diagram, and from the size of the package on the example PCB layout in the datasheet. It looks like they're expecting an electrolytic.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Microfarads.

And yes, there is a hint, of sorts. Polarized caps on power supplies are almost always in microfarads. Farads/millifarads are just unreasonably large values, and nano/pico farads too small to do anything. Sometimes you'll see a combination such as a 10 in parallel with a 0.1, and in both cases those are microfarads, although the 0.1 will want to be a ceramic for good high-frequency performance.